# Ada Print Port_Type

Tags: ada

how to put_line Port_Type as defined in g-socket.ads:492, please?

```
Ada.Text_io.Put_Line ("Port: "  & Integer'Image(Port));
```

give me
found type "Port_Type" defined at g-socket.ads:492
xxx.adb:121:51: expected type "Standard.Integer"
Thanks
BR
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write

```ada
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Port: "  & Port'Image);
```

or, if you’re using an older GNAT,

```ada
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Port: "  & Port'Img);
```

`’Image` works for scalars; in Ada 2022 it works for composite types as well. There’s heavy stuff in [ARM 2022 4.10, Image Attributes](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-4-10.html)

Comment: Nice Simon. This is OK & obvious.. Many thanks Simon. mark

Comment: @Mark If you like this answer, make sure to mark it as a solution as well.

Comment: You should also be able to do `Port_Type'Image (Port)`.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter Thanks for this, I thought of it an hour ago. The interesting point for a newcomer to Ada is that while `Port_Type` has the integer nature, it’s not an `Integer`. If one enjoyed typing, one could say `Integer’Image (Integer (Port))`.